# Find java build version of the class files in a jar file using ant?

Tags: ant

Is there an ant task which allows me to look at some jar file and figure out which Java version the class files in the jar were compiled for?

Comment: I'm curious... why do you want to do this?

Comment: We have a deployment ant task. As part of the deploy there are a bunch of jar files. Sometimes depending on which developer compiles them the jar is compiled with the wrong version. We've corrected that on the build ant script of those jars however I would like to add a just in case check on the deploy to warn if any jar is not targeting the desired jvm version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to write one.  You could do it with existing tasks, but it's going to be ugly - this isn't really what ant shines at.

You could unzip the jar, and then either exec out to file (unix like machines), you see this one is version 51 (java 7)

```
$file MyClass.class
MyClass.class; compiled Java class data, version 51.0
```

or if you're using windows you could use `javap -v`

```
$javap -v MyClass.class
Classfile 
MyClass.class
  Last modified Sep 24, 2013; size 7317 bytes
  MD5 checksum 73667731fe2ec6519b1c0c4676a96c70
public class com.foo.MyClass
  minor version: 0
  major version: 51
```

You'd then have to use use replaceregex or some sauce to find the major version.

You're going to better off writing a small task, you can use Apache's [byte code engineering library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel) to pull out the version.